# How to input a text file into a java program via terminal (like how it's done in C++)?

Tags: java, input, terminal

If i do

> `$ java ProgramName string1 string2 string3`

from the linux terminal, ProgramName gets string1 string2 string3 via `main(String arg[])` using `arg[i]`, and all is well.

Here's what I want to do:
Instead of typing `string1 string2 string3` at the terminal, i want to type

> `$ java ProgramName < input.txt`

where "input.txt" contains string1, string2, and string3

Edit:
"input.txt" has one word on a separate line with an 'enter' at the end of the line

```
string1

string2

stringn
```

This can be done it C++ ; can it be done similarly in Java?

Comment: Does your ProgramName check for a file in the arg[] and open that file for reading strings from? if not then this will not work.

Comment: To do what you want, try reading the 3 strings from System.in which is where Unix standard input (which you're redirecting to a file) is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
export parameters=`cat file.txt`
java programname $parameters
```

note the inverse **`** (not ')

or even:

```
java programname `cat file.txt`
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are redirecting a file to the standard input of your program, you can try the following:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = new String();
while(in.hasNext())//while there are lines on the file
{
    line = in.nextLine();//read the line
    //do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this command:

```
java MyProg "$(cat file.txt | tr '\n' ' ')"
```

If its not working please check that arguments are properly defined in source file.

Comment: this works when "input.txt" has only 1 string on 1 line, but string2 and stringn were not read by ProgramName.  Is this related to "If its not working please check that arguments are properly defined in source file. "